# Create Directory if it doesn't exist with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a directory with the following code:

```
Dir.mkdir("/Users/Luigi/Desktop/Survey_Final/Archived/Survey/test")
    unless File.exists?("/Users/Luigi/Desktop/Survey_Final/Archived/Survey/test")
```

However, I'm receiving this error:

> No such file or directory - /Users/Luigi/Desktop/Survey_Final/Archived/Survey/test (Errno::ENOENT)

Why is this directory not being created by the `Dir.mkdir` statement above?

Comment: `File.exists?()` works on files and folders. It doesn't know the difference.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

You are probably trying to create nested directories. Assuming `foo` does not exist, you will receive `no such file or directory` error for:

```
Dir.mkdir 'foo/bar'
# => Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 'foo/bar'
```

To create nested directories at once, `FileUtils` is needed:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p 'foo/bar'
# => ["foo/bar"]
```

Edit2: you do not have to use `FileUtils`, you may do system call (update from @mu is too short comment):

```
> system 'mkdir', '-p', 'foo/bar' # worse version: system 'mkdir -p "foo/bar"'
=> true
```

But that seems (at least to me) as worse approach as you are using external 'tool' which may be unavailable on some systems (although I can hardly imagine system without `mkdir`, but who knows).

Comment: `system 'mkdir', '-p', 'foo/bar'` would be a better version of that `system` call. There's no need for an extra shell process or the usual quoting/escaping/injection nonsense that comes with the single argument version of `system`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, what do you mean by extra shell process?

Comment: `system` will launch `/bin/sh` to parse the `mkdir -p "foo/bar"` string and then the shell will run `/bin/mkdir`. So you're doing extra work (create the command string, launch `/bin/sh` to pull it apart again) and some of that extra work leaves you open to shell injection attacks (spend some time in the CERT advisories for Ruby and you'll see how common this problem is).

Comment: @muistooshort @zrl3dx how is a `system` call better than `fileutils` again? I'm on Windows and `mkdir_p` works just fine without spawning a subshell just to parse `mkdir -p` which would fail anyway. Glad that `fileutils` is the first alternative in the answer.

Comment: @TWiStErRob: Read my comments again, I said nothing about `fileutils` or `mkdir_p`, all I'm saying is that `system command, arg1, arg2, ...` is better than `system command_with_arguments`.

Comment: @muistooshort ah, sorry, so you're just saying that there's a better way of doing the bad option :)

Comment: Using system, whether or not you create a subshell, is around two orders of magnitude slower than FileUtils.mkdir_p.  I don't know why it should be suggested at all.

Comment: Do not use system calls. System calls should be always avoided. It is slower and it is not usable on all OSs.

Comment: Do not use `::` for method calls. Use the `dot` instead , like so `FileUtils.mkdir_p`, not `FileUtils::mkdir_p`

Answer (score 86):

Simple way:

```
directory_name = "name"
Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
```

Comment: One shall use File.directory? rather than File.exists?

Comment: Suppose there's a normal file with the same name. You couldn't create a directory in such case.

Comment: It also creates a race condition. The file may be created after the check but before creation.

Comment: @DonReba How so? Are the methods File.exists? and Dir.mkdir asynchronous?

Comment: @Licysca please consider updating your answer. This is not a clean answer and it is getting unjustified upvotes.

Comment: File.exists? is deprecated in favor of File.exist?

Answer (score 35):

Another simple way:

`Dir.mkdir('tmp/excel') unless Dir.exist?('tmp/excel')`

Comment: If you want to create nested directories then this doesn't work. For e.g I wanted to create following  directory `/home/jignesh/reports/test` but using this solution raised `RUBY (Errno::ENOENT), no such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir`. So the reliable solution is using `FileUtils.mkdir_p`

Comment: This might be unreliable on a powerful server with many simultaneous processes because *after* Dir.exist? but *before* Dir.mkdir another process may create the same directory. For this reason I prefer Vidar's suggestion below except that I would prefer to catch only "File Exists" exception.

Answer (score -8):

How about just `Dir.mkdir('dir') rescue nil` ?

Comment: Avoid using `rescue` in its modifier form.

Comment: Care to explain why I should write 5 lines of code instead of just 1? I'd like to see you try.

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-rescue-modifiers have a look, please

Comment: I already did, and I totally disagree, I think it's silly, so maybe you can enlighten me?

Comment: This would catch *any* exception which is not what you're trying to do and in a real world app would hide problems making maintenance harder. Also, its not a great idea to use exceptions as conditionals, in a hardware sense they run much much slower (likely not really an issue in a modern language but still makes you look inexperienced as a coder).

Comment: In addition to what's been mentioned, if something goes wrong this totally silences the error. If you use a block, you have the chance to log diagnostics, which you almost certainly should do in the common case.

Comment: Actually Vidar's answer is probably the best one because when you
Dir.mkdir('tmp/excel') unless Dir.exist?('tmp/excel')
another process may create the directory *after* Dir.exist? but before Dir.mkdir. For college homework this probably does not matter though.