# How do I create a subdirectory if no one exists when writing to a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I am creating a CSV file like this:

```
    CSV.open("#{city}.csv", "a+") do |csv|
      csv << listing
    end
```

But, ideally I would like to do `results/#{city}.csv`, if that file doesn't exist.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: i guess CSV from ruby stdlib does not support creating directories on the fly.
Most probably you need to create it manually before writing to csv file.

Comment: @RubaRuba Interesting, care to illustrate with code? Also, I was hesitant about having a FileUtils call before writing each line to CSV....feels like overkill.

Comment: well, you don't need to do something before you write each line. Just before opening block `CSV.open ...`check if dir you need exists or create it.
`File.directory?("results") || FileUtils.mkdir "results"`
thats what i meant.

Comment: Also, have a look at this [Create Directory if it doesn't exist with Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280341/create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-with-ruby)

Comment: @RubaRuba Can you leave a complete answer please. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
require "fileutils"

csvfile= 'tmp/folder1/folder2/folder3/foo.csv'

FileUtils::mkdir_p File.dirname csvfile
```

`mkdir_p` is line gnu `mkdir -p` which creates the directory structure for you, and won't complain if the directory already exists.

`dirname` returns the directory name.

If you want specify permissions when creating the directory do this:

```
FileUtils::mkdir_p( File.dirname(csvfile) , :mode => 0777)
```

Comment: I tried this, but now I am getting this error: `fileutils.rb:253:in mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /results (Errno::EACCES)`. This is what I did: `csvfile= "/results/#{state}/#{city}.csv" FileUtils::mkdir_p File.dirname csvfile`

Comment: I never did that. I just simply ran the script and it gave me that. I didn't customize any user permissions or anything like that.

Comment: @marcamillion thinking better about the problem, you're trying to create a folder under the `/` that usually needs a privileged user. try creating it under your home directory or under `/tmp`

Comment: I want the folder to be a subfolder on my project.....not my in some random folder.

Comment: I tried your modified statement with that `:mode => 0777` and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Actually i figured it out. Turns out that I had a slash at the beginning of the directory path which is what was throwing it off kilter it seems. Once I removed that initial `/` everything works like you would expect. So thanks much!